# Should - what's meaning

Tags: meaning

Here are 2 sentences:

"I was surprised that he should say such a thing."

and

"I was surprised that he said such a thing."

Is there are any difference in meaning between them?

Answer (score 1):

The modal **should** underscores the 'distance' between expectation and reality.

**Should** is a modal auxiliary with a number of shades of meaning, but one here could be habitual action, or inclination, that something is "in someone's character".

I am surprised that **he** should say such a thing (because I think it is not in his character to say such a thing).

It can also express *improbability*.

I am surprised that he should say **such** a thing (because the facts were otherwise, and I find such a contradiction of the facts to be an improbability).

Another way of understanding the modal **should** here is as a marker of allegation. He is *reputed to have said*.

Comment: You are right, of course, but the general expectation on ELU is that all answers be supported (by prose justifications, reference works, citations to authorities, etc). But given the OP's likely learning English as a foreign language, perhaps the best course of action would be to migrate the question over to ELL, where this answer could stand as-is? What do you think?

Comment: I don't know how to migrate them. But please feel free to do so.

Comment: Your answer is beefier now, and I'm happy with it. If others decide to migrate, that's ok too, but in satisfied with the Q&A as is.